# Do flash movies share classes in the same virtual machine?

Tags: flash, actionscript, virtual-machine, static-variables

Imagine a `parent.swf` that loads a `child.swf` via `flash.display.Loader` and both contain the same class:

```
package com.company {
   public class MyClass {
      public static var x:int;
   }
}
```

Will these two classes share the static variable `x` or will each movieclip have their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I made a small test to just check the behaviour and it seems that the movieclips do not share the same static variable. Each of them has their own even though exactly the same class has been used during compile time.

Comment: Do you mean "do not share"?

Answer (score 0):

There should only be one class ... you can use use the MXMLC compiler for example to exclude the class from the child swf, which has a dependency to the parent. Then you could avoid such troubles. The trouble I am speaking of is having a newer SWF containing a modified version of `MyClass`. This would lead to a naming collision.

Comment: i forgot to mention this, but in my example both movieclips are compiled using exactly the same class. so that is actually on purpose and is not a naming conflict.

Comment: Then there is only one class ```MyClass```.

Comment: Actually my simple testprogram proves the opposite.

Comment: And there can't be any sandbox/ApplicationDomain issue involved? Can you access properties from within the child/parent in the loading/loaded SWF?